# D3js json based input for widgets - Json format

Tags: json, d3.js

let me describe my case and would like to get your opinions on that.
I am planning a UI for an app which aims to represent a vast amount of data graphically. For that I have decided to use the awesome visualizations of d3. On the one side I have a repository of a vast amount of stored data and on the other side I have an app UI that uses three different d3js widgets (forced graph, coffee flavor wheel and circle graph) to visualize some aspects of that data repository. The main input for any of the three widgets will be a .json file. Each of the d3 widgets has its own specifics in terms of visualizing data in a different manner and that requires some differences in the "input" .json file that feeds it. My question is, is there a kind of minimal set of basic data that the input .json file needs to contain so that it can be used for building ANY of the d3 widgets (or at least the three ones I have pointed here)? Something like for example "containing at least the main nodes, their values and their relations with other nodes" or anything like that?

Thanks in advance for your answers :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming (I think!) that all processing of data will be done on your data server.  You might also consider processing it in javascript.  It will depend on the size of data and processing required whether this makes sense or not.

If you are serving large data files, you might find it quicker to send your data as csv files (they are smaller than json) and process them as required in javascript.  For example, send flat csv file and create a hierarchy using d3.nest for the force graph and coffee wheel https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_nest or slice and dice the data using crossfilter. http://square.github.com/crossfilter/